# What is the most efficient way to reuse a UICollectoinView for 60 different Parse.com queries?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I am currently re-querying the UICollectionView every time the UICollectionView is called on viewDidLoad(). It's taking forever to download all of my images. I want to download all of them once at the start of the app and then be able to call them quickly depending on which collection is selected. My code is here:

UICollectionView code:

```
var exp = ""

class CollectionCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    images = []
    parseObjects = []
    imageNames = []
    imageExpansions = []

    var downloadCards = PFQuery(className: "Cards")
    downloadCards.whereKey("ExpansionNumber", equalTo:"\(exp)")
    downloadCards.orderByAscending("Number")
    downloadCards.limit = 200
    downloadCards.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) cards.")
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    parseObjects.append(object["Image"] as! PFFile)
                    imageNames.append(object["Number"] as! String)
                    imageExpansions.append(object["ExpansionNumber"] as! String)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return parseObjects.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: CardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell

    parseObjects[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            cell.cardsImg.image = image

        }   

    }
    //cell.cardLabel.text = imageNames[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}
```

Segue and collection identifier code:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
var parseObjects = [PFFile]()
var imageNames = [String]()
var imageExpansions = [String]()

class selectExpansionViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func xy1Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "\(sender.tag)"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a collection view reuse issue, it's a data management issue. In particular, you repeatedly download images instead of caching them.

The simple option is to use a `PFImageView` to handle the image `PFFile`s, because it caches the images to disk once downloaded. It doesn't give you a great deal of control over that cache however so you might want to consider organising a cache yourself.

In this way you will download only the objects during `viewDidLoad`, each having a reference to the image file URL and then (in whatever way you choose) check to see if the image for that URL has already been downloaded so you can simply reuse it.